# magento newsletter subscription not working in magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: php, magento

newsletter subscription not working in all pages. no newsletter confirmation mail send to customers

```
<div class="custom-subscribe">
<div class="title">
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Newsletter') ?></span>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">

    <div class="form-subscribe-header">
        <label for="newsletter"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:') ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
       <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solutions:

In the Magento backend "System > Permissions > Variables" and "System > Permissions > Blocks"

Add newsletter/subscribe and refreshed cache.

More info:

There is a new check on the template directive, see `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::blockDirective()` line 176

```
 if ($this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
        $type = $blockParameters['type'];
        $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
    }
```

Also check in system configuration as below:

```
 System--->Advanced--->Advanced
```